# Extracting multiple nodes from an XML document with xmllint

Tags: xml, xmllint

I am trying to use xmllint in order to extract multiple nodes under multiple parent nodes called `//item`, as follows:

```
<item>
        <title>A title</title>
        <link>http://www.example.com</link>
        <pubDate>Mon, 08 Aug 2016 09:04:11 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><a name></dc:creator>
        <location><a name></dc:creator>
</item>
```

I would normally do this if I simply want to extract of node (for example title):

```
xmllint --shell myXml.xml
```

and then `cat //item/title`, this will only retrieve all the title tags and their values. Can i use xmllint to get a subset of nodes, for example:

```
        <title>A title</title>
        <link>http://www.example.com</link>
        <pubDate>Mon, 08 Aug 2016 09:04:11 +0000</pubDate>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative XPath to get multiple elements of different name using `self` axis and union (`|`) operator :

```
cat //item/*[self::title|self::link|self::pubDate]
 -------
<title>A title</title>
 -------
<link>http://www.example.com</link>
 -------
<pubDate>Mon, 08 Aug 2016 09:04:11 +0000</pubDate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `or` for the element names:

```
cat //item/*[name()="title" or name()="link" or name()="pubDate"]
```

I had to fix your XML to make it well formed.

Or, use a more advanced tool, for example [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) (which I happen to maintain):

```
for //item ls ( title | link | pubDate ) ;
```